# Problems loading two libraries

Tags: r, libraries

I am trying to install the libraries plotKML and spatialEco in a standard way, with `library()`.
However, despiste I updated R, updated all my libraries, and tried reinstalling them, I keep getting the next errors:

```
> library(plotKML)
plotKML version 0.6-1 (2020-03-08)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plotKML’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'plotKML', details:
  call: CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
  error: NA
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘plotKML’ was built under R version 4.0.3

> library(spatialEco)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘spatialEco’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'units', details:
  call: udunits_init(file.path(.get_ud_xml_dir(), "udunits2.xml"))
  error: Error in function udunits_init: Can't open installed, default, unit database
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘spatialEco’ was built under R version 4.0.3
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is your R version?

Comment: `library()` loads and attaches the (namespace of the) package; it doesn't install the package.  I assume you installed the packages with `install.packages(c("plotKML", "spatialEco"))`? Did the installation proceed without errors? Do you also get the errors if you start from a clean R session (don't load an old environment)?

Comment: I had 4.0.2, now 4.0.4, but I get the same error

Comment: Alright, I tried uninstalling plotKML, starting a new version and instaling it with install.packages("plotKML",dependencies=T). When doing this I found out one of the dependencies (spcosa) is not available for this version, this is likely the error, thank you